# How to display PHP date in Turkish?

Tags: php, date, time, localization

How can I display the date in Turkish language?
I'm trying following code but it does not print anything at all.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8');
echo strftime("%e %B %Y %A", time());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though i don't understand turkish but it is printing output

```
  14 Şubat 2013 Perşembe
```

So your code is fine.
Hope you are not missing out php tags. :/

Comment: I'm not missing anything but I think its my PHP version. Which version of PHP you tested?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
            setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8');
            echo strftime("%e %B %Y %A", time());
          ?>
```

Prints out: 30 Ekim 2015 Cuma

Code works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Php date for "F" which gives month of English name to translate to Turkish given example

```
date("d F")
```

you can use this function

```
   function convertMonthToTurkishCharacter($date){
    $aylar = array(
        'January'    =>    'Ocak',
        'February'    =>    'Şubat',
        'March'        =>    'Mart',
        'April'        =>    'Nisan',
        'May'        =>    'Mayıs',
        'June'        =>    'Haziran',
        'July'        =>    'Temmuz',
        'August'    =>    'Ağustos',
        'September'    =>    'Eylül',
        'October'    =>    'Ekim',
        'November'    =>    'Kasım',
        'December'    =>    'Aralık',
        'Monday'    =>    'Pazartesi',
        'Tuesday'    =>    'Salı',
        'Wednesday'    =>    'Çarşamba',
        'Thursday'    =>    'Perşembe',
        'Friday'    =>    'Cuma',
        'Saturday'    =>    'Cumartesi',
        'Sunday'    =>    'Pazar',
        'Jan' => 'Oca',
        'Feb' => 'Şub',
        'Mar' => 'Mar',
        'Apr' => 'Nis',
        'May' => 'May',
        'Jun' => 'Haz',
        'Jul' => 'Tem',
        'Aug' => 'Ağu',
        'Sep' => 'Eyl',
        'Oct' => 'Eki',
        'Nov' => 'Kas',
        'Dec' => 'Ara'

    );
    return  strtr($date, $aylar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add it before the code.

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8', 'tr_TR', 'tr', 'turkish');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public function getTurkishDate(){
       $locale = 'tr_TR'; // a canonicalized locale
       $format = 'dd-MMMM-YYYY'; // ISO format codes, not the typical date ones
       $dt = new DateTime(); // a DateTime object
       $df = new IntlDateFormatter(
           $locale, // string locale
           IntlDateFormatter::NONE, // int date type
           IntlDateFormatter::NONE, // int time type
           'UTC', // string timezone
           IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, // int cal type
           $format // string pattern
       );
       return $df->format($dt); //string 07-Ağustos-2018
    }
```

OR

```
    public function getTurkishDate(){
        $locale = 'tr_TR'; // a canonicalized locale
        $format = 'dd-MMMM-YYYY-EEEE'; // ISO format codes, not the typical date ones
        $dt = new DateTime(); // a DateTime object
        $df = new IntlDateFormatter(
            $locale, // string locale
            IntlDateFormatter::NONE, // int date type
            IntlDateFormatter::NONE, // int time type
            'UTC', // string timezone
            IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, // int cal type
            $format // string pattern);
        return $df->format($dt); //string 07-Ağustos-2018-Salı
    }
```

OR

```
    public function getTurkishDate(){
        $locale = 'tr_TR'; // a canonicalized locale
        $format = 'dd-MMMM-YYYY-ee'; // ISO format codes, not the typical date ones
        $dt = new DateTime(); // a DateTime object
        $df = new IntlDateFormatter(
            $locale, // string locale
            IntlDateFormatter::NONE, // int date type
            IntlDateFormatter::NONE, // int time type
            'UTC', // string timezone
            IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, // int cal type
            $format // string pattern);
        return $df->format($dt); //string 07-Ağustos-2018-02
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take current date and time with:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Istanbul");
//echo "The time is " . date("H:i") . "<br>";
//echo "Today is " . date("Y-m-d") . "<br>";
//echo "Today is " . date("l");
$now_time = date("H:i");
$now_date = date("Y-m-d");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First activate extension extension=intl in php.ini

then gentle restart in cmd C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -k restart

Use date2() function below,date2 is working well.

```
function date2($format,$unixtimestamp=0){
    $dt = new DateTime();   
    if($unixtimestamp>0){
        $dt->setTimestamp($unixtimestamp);
    }
    $locale = 'tr_TR'; // a canonicalized locale
    // ISO format codes, not the typical date ones
    $df = new IntlDateFormatter(
        $locale,
        IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 
        IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 
        'UTC', // timezone
        IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, // int cal type
        $format 
    );
    return $df->format($dt); //string 07-Ağustos-2018-Salı
}

echo date2("d / M MM / Y MMM MMMM EE EEEE",time());
```